# Proving that no two teams in a tournament win same number of games

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinations

Assume we've a tournament with $93$ teams. And between every $19$ teams, there is one team that has lost all of its $18$ games to other teams, and there is one team that has won all of its $18$ games against the other teams.
Between all teams, there is one match and only possible results for a match is win and lose.

My own idea is to try to give a proof by contradiction, by assuming two teams share same number of games won.

Comment: I'm going to see how far I get using the Pigeonhole principle...

Comment: @ColmBhandal Let's dive into it...

Comment: The pigeonhole principle would be great for proving that two teams _did_ have to have the same number of wins. But it's not immediately clear how it can be bent the other direction, to show that a set of things must all be different.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki you're right I'm realising the same thing.

Comment: I have a feeling that you need to show the teams form a totally ordered set...

Comment: @ColmBhandal Yes. Some feeling of chain comes in mind when trying to group teams in different groups with size 19. And I think totally ordered set would be useful. But how to implement it to solve the question? I have no idea yet.

Comment: I have no idea either. I'm just annoyingly thinking aloud. But the question is equivalent to asking you to prove that the teams form a total order in terms of their wins. Uniquness implies that the wins go $92, 91, \dots, 0$, which in turn implies total order...

Comment: OK, I might have something. The first team to break the pattern $0, 1, 2, \dots$ is interesting, I think...

Comment: @ColmBhandal can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: Nah forget it, I was trying to proceed as follows. "We want to show the wins go $0, 1, 2, \dots, 92$. Then suppose this wasn't true. There'd be a first team with wins $k$ that didn't follow the sequence. I got nowhere. I'm currently trying to show that there are no cycles in the graph, which is again equivalent. All I've done is trivially shown no cycles of length $19$, which follows directly from the question.

Comment: The exact numbers $93$ and $19$ are not important other than the fact that $93 \geq 19 \times 2 > 4$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki actually you can also use the pigeonhole principle in a "Positive" way. It's a less formal way of saying that a surjective function between finite sets of the same size is also injective (and thus bijective).

Comment: @MTP1376 I challenge you to extend my proof to fully cover all cases- show that for sufficiently large $k$ relative to $n$, it is possible to construct a $k$ absolute set that is *not* totally ordered. There may be a few sticky corner cases to do individually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definition top/bottom element:** In a set $S$ a team is the top element if it has won against everyone else. It is the bottom if it has lost against everyone else.

**Definition:** Let's say that a set of teams is $k$ absolute if every subset of size $k$ of these teams has both a top and a bottom element.

**To prove:** You want to show your teams form a total order in terms of the win/lose relation. Here is a general proof that a total order exists for any $n$ teams which are $k$ absolute whenever $n \geq 2k > 4$. In your case, $n, k$ are $93, 19$ respectively, fitting the above inequality.

**Proof:** Suppose you have $n \geq 2k$ nodes. We can prove they form a total order as follows. Pull off the top node to get a $k$ absolute set of $n-1$ elements. Then pull off the top node again to get a $k$ absolute set of $n-2$ elements. Repeat until you're left with $k$ elements. You are allowed to do this until you get to $k$ by the "top" part of the top-bottom lemma. This gives you that there are teams with $k+1, k+2, \dots, n$ wins. Now, do the same for the least elements, again using the top-bottom lemma- this time the "bottom" part. You end up showing there are teams with $1, 2, \dots, k$ wins; you can stop at $k$ even if $n > 2k$ becausee you've already shown the wins from $k+1$ onwards. Together, then these results show that we have some team with $1$ win, another with $2$ etc. all the way up to $n$. This implies uniqueness by the pigeonhole principle because we have $n$ pigeons (teams) and $n$ holes (number of wins) and there exists a team for each number of wins.

**Lemma (Top/Bottom):** We show that every $k$ absolute set $U$ of $n$ teams with $n \geq k > 2$ elements has a top and a bottom element. We prove this as follows. Let $S$ be the largest subset of $U$ that has a top element. We know by $k$ absoluteness of $U$ that $|S| \geq k$. Now, suppose $S \neq U$, towards a contradiction. Let $t$ be the top element of $S$. Then we can choose some $u \in U$ s.t. $u > t$. Now, we can show that $u$ is the top element in $S \cup \{u\}$. To show this, consider any subset of $S$ of size $|S| - 1$ that also contains $t$. Call it $S'$. Because $k > 2$, every element in $S$ belongs to some such $S'$; a crucial point made by commenter Steve Kass is that this is not the case for $k = 2$. Now, by $k$ absoluteness, there must be a top element of $S' \cup \{u\}$. Well, because $t$ is greater than all elements existing other than $u$, none of them can be the top. Nor can $t$ be the top since $u>t$. So $u$ is the top element. So, $u$ is greater than all elements of $S'$. Since we've already mentioned that every element of $S$ is in some $S'$, because $k>2$, we know then that $u > s$ for every $s \in S$. Thus the set $S \cup \{u\}$ of size strictly greater than $S$, has a top element $u$, contradicting our assumption that $S$ was the top. Thus, $U$ must have a top element. The exact same argument can be applied for a bottom element.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a better way to explain this and that it's a known proof in lattice theory or something that I saw years ago, but hopefully you get the rough idea.

Comment: I think this is pretty close to a proof (and is the same as what I came up with while thinking on this in the shower), but there are a couple of tiny things: (1) your 'clearly' could use some fleshing out ($t$ can't be the top element of the subset because $u\gt t$, and nothing else can be because $t$ is still greater than everything else in the subset), and (2) this procedure doesn't _quite_ work as written: consider an 'order' $0\lt 1\lt 2\lt\ldots39\lt 40\lt 0$. Then the procedure you've written will never find a top element.

Comment: (Assuming that you start with the set $\{0\ldots18\}$

Comment: Maybe I’m missing something, but consider a set of $n=3$ teams, each of which has played the other two teams with a $1$-$1$ record. (A beat B, B beat C, and C beat A; the tournament graph is a $3$-cycle.) This (or any) tournament is $2$-absolute, because within any subset of two teams, there is a top and bottom element (the winner and loser of the single match between those two teams.

So the graph of any $n$-team tournament is $2$-absolute, and with $k=2$, $n>2k>2$ for any $n>4$. Then your work concludes than any $n$-tournament is transitive so long as $n>4$. I don’t think this is correct.

Comment: @SteveKass dammit! I meand $k>2$ aka $2k > 4$ thank you for the correction! I also went through the case of $2$ absoluteness and realised it was special.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I was hoping I'd get away with this. The full proof is in my head. I'll elaborate now!